# Does any Windows Phone have Pattern Lock feature just like Android?

Tags: lock-screen, nokia-lumia-525

I love Android’s pattern lock feature and I wish to use it in my Windows Phone (Lumia 525). Is there any way or App to use that feature? Does any Windows Phone have Pattern lock feature just like Android?

[image]

Comment: How does the pattern lock feature work on Android?

Comment: AFAK It's In-built in Android Phones comes with OS.

Comment: how would you describe what it does, and how it works to someone that had never used it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the writing of this, pattern unlock isn't supported on Windows Phone. The only option for protecting your phone is currently a PIN code.

[Windows Phone 8 - Lock screen FAQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/lock-screen-faq)

That said, it seems there is an unofficial app in the works that would add pattern unlock using the new Live Lock Screen feature in Windows Phone 8.1:

[New Live Lock Screen adds Pattern Lock to WP8.1](http://wmpoweruser.com/new-live-lock-screen-adds-pattern-lock-to-wp8-1)

It doesn't seem to be actually available yet (at least I couldn't find a download link anywhere), but is something to keep your eye on nonetheless.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the Live Lock screen app isn't compatible with kid's corner.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for an open source control which helps you to do enable pattern lock in your application then you can follow this [blog Pattern Lock for Windows Phone](http://nishantcop.blogspot.in/2014/02/pattern-lock-for-windows-phone.html) which has a similar control and it's free.